# Could not load type 'System.Object' from assembly 'System.RunTime, Version=6.0.0.0

Tags: .net, wix, .net-6.0, .net-4.8, .net-runtime

Previously my application was build on .net framework 4.8 and the setup has done by using wix toolset version 3.11.2 . due to some reason we have migrated some of the component into .net .standard 2.0 and one of the project in to .net 6 because it was a console application. and we are able to build and the application using visual studio.

in wix .msm file we have setup the assemblies like this .

```
<Component Id="_COMP_Data_UI_dll" Guid="{b55258eb-3a2a-4575-afd1-1385beb03c01}">
            <File Id="_FILE_Data_UI_dll" Name="Data.UI.dll" KeyPath="yes"  Assembly=".net" AssemblyManifest="_FILE_Data_UI_dll" AssemblyApplication="_FILE_Data_UI_dll" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Data.UI.dll" />
        </Component>
```

since .net 6 doesn't support AssemblyManifest, Assembly attributes in wix I have removed those attributes.

```
<Component Id="_COMP_Data_UI_dll" Guid="{b55258eb-3a2a-4575-afd1-1385beb03c01}">
   <File Id="_FILE_Data_UI_dll" Name="Data.UI.dll" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Data.UI.dll" /> 
</Component>
```

now when I create the setup ,I am able to create and after installation , but i got a message that Could not load type 'System.Object' from assembly 'System.Runtime.dll version 6.0.0.0" in the event viewer if add the 'System.Runtime.dll" in to gac then it shows unable to to System.Private.CoreLib.dll.

[image]

so the problem is both .net framwork and .net 6 are belongs to one .msm file and that msm has taken in .msi file and that msi has take in bootstarper by using Msipackage tag , so is it possible to keep .net framework and .net 6 in one msm so that two types of runtime.dll can run those two types of assembly as per the request.